# Переменная rb не существует в данном контексте

Tags: c#, unity3d, context

Переменная rb не существует в данном контексте, если написать перед rb слово public, то будет другая ошибка: Type or namespace defenition, or end-of-file expected. В первом случае ошибку вызывает строка  rb.AddForce, а во втором фигурная скобка которая закрывает тело класса.

```
void Start()
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up*20, Color.white, 1, false);
    if(hit.distance <= 15)
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.position - hit.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном примере идет попытка создания *поля* внутри метода, что, конечно же, непозволительно. Поля принадлежат классу, а не методу - методу принадлежат переменные.

Предлагаю вынести объявление поля в нужное ему место - над методом `Start`:

`public Rigidbody2D rb;`. А в самом методе оставить лишь присваивание:

```
rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

Тогда поле будет доступно в любом контексте: этого и других классов.